how to validate array field in vee-validate
I am new with vee-validate 4 and quasar .
now I have form like this :
    <q-form @submit="onSubmit" class="form " id="myform">
      <q-input class="col-span-2" filled dense v-model="title" label="Title *" v-bind="titleProps" />
      <q-input filled dense v-model="name" label="Name *" v-bind="nameProps" />
      <q-input filled dense v-model="description" label="Description" v-bind="descriptionProps" />
      <q-option-group class="col-span-2" inline v-model="permissions" :options="modifiedPermissions"
        type="checkbox" />
    </q-form>

this is schema for it
const createSchema = toTypedSchema(
  yup.object({
    title: yup.string().required().label('title'),
    name: yup.string().required().label('Name'),
    description: yup.string().optional().label('description'),
    permissions: yup.array().of(yup.number().required('Please select at least one permission')).required().min(1, 'Please select at least one permission'), // Enforce minimum of 1 permission
  }),
);
const { defineField, handleSubmit: validate, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema: createSchema,

});
const quasarConfig = (state: { errors: string[] }) => ({
  props: {
    error: !!state.errors[0],
    'error-message': state.errors[0],
  },
  validateOnModelUpdate: false
});
const [name, nameProps] = defineField('name', quasarConfig);
const [title, titleProps] = defineField('title', quasarConfig);
const [description, descriptionProps] = defineField('description', quasarConfig);
const [permissions, permissionsProps] = defineField('permissions',quasarConfig);

the problem is that **permissions **field is not an array
so how can make it array of numbers ??
